# Random forest classifier R : returning Probabilities instead of factor

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

The below code ideally should return y_pred_randomForest as a factor with two levels

```
randomForest_classifier= randomForest(x=training_set[-y_pos],y=training_set[y_pos],ntree=10)
y_pred_randomForest= predict(randomForest_classifier,newdata=test_set[-y_pos],type='class')
```

But its returning probabilties instead.

```
head(y_pred_randomForest)

1         5        14        16        18        21 
0.2220672 0.3300000 0.1750000 0.7200000 0.1200000 0.2000000
```

Thanks , your help is appreciated

Comment: I think you need `type="response"`, but that should be equivalent to `type="class"` (which is allowed, but is converted to `type="response"`). Just to confirm: Your outcome variable is factor, rather than numeric?

Comment: I was gonna ask if the outcome is a factor and not numeric

Comment: I need my outcome to be factor with two levels. But I am getting a numeric outcome